# Is there an example where a parametric polynomial curve a proper subset of any containing affine algebraic variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am just a beginner to computational algebraic geometry and I am reading

[Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms](http://www.springer.com/it/book/9781441922571)

I have just done with a problem in chapter 2, section 1, question 5. With the help of the question, I was able to prove that a polynomial parametric curve is always contained in an affine algebraic variety.

Here is my [proof](http://andrew-exercise.blogspot.com/2016/02/utm-ideals-varieties-and-algorithm_24.html). I think this is pretty much what the problem statement tell me to do.

After doing so, I wonder, can we do the other inclusion? Is it possible to prove a point on the polynomial I found is actually on the parametric curve, or can I find a counterexample that any polynomial I can found will have some point outside of the parametric curve (assuming that is no specify range for the parameter $ t $ in question)

Comment: Is $k$ algebraically closed?

Comment: If $k$ is not algebraically closed you don't get all the points: for example $x=t^2,y=t^4$ only reaches half the points of the parabola $y=x^2$ on which the parametrized curve lies (those with $x\geq 0$). For $k$  algebraically closed all points of the supporting curve are reached, because the parametrizing morphism is finite.

Comment: Thank you for the comments!